# How can I implement filter in Navigation Drawer List Item

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-filterable

[image]

I have a long list item on navigation drawer, I have added an EditText on top of it, but also implemented filterable on the custom adapter, but application crashes when I add this line of code

```
EditText searchSongs = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchInput);

    if(adapter != null) {
        searchSongs.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                //adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
```

If I remove the code everything works perfectly well, even when I comment out the getFilter method, still crashes.

Comment: Post your logcat, so that ppl here can help you.

Comment: mDrawerList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();

Comment: Thank you, I later used SearchView to achieve that,